# Many (or all) default Windows 10 icons and also some others have no icons in taskbar or search, but do in start menu when I look manually

Tags: windows-10, icons, windows-search

So recently I've noticed that some default aka pre-installed Windows 10 apps have a placeholder file app icon that looks like white paper that is folded in the top right corner. I also made a list of all the apps that I've seen to have this problem: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1UcpSckevxvP7A5iVN5cA6ojisu1bLMPwnG6Ls91JGw0/edit?usp=sharing

So far I've tried to:

- Remove Google Drive File Stream / Uninstall Google Drive desktop
- Reset the IconCache.db (https://techcult.com/fix-windows-10-taskbar-icons-missing/#Method_7_Reset_Icon_Cache)
- Disable Tablet mode
- Update display driver, but it's up-to-date
- Reset the app from Windows settings

And none of these things worked.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have Live Tiles disabled or some issue with them. I believe they're tied in with push and toast notifications.

Have a look at the registry values here for how to force configure them. Requires reboot.
https://admx.help/HKCU/SOFTWARE/Policies/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/PushNotifications

But first I'd create a new local user and see if the issue follows. If you have local machine or group policy pushing the change the new user account might not get you anywhere though.

Comment: I did create a new user and the problem wasn't there, at least I think, I can't fully remember though